# Whats the equivalent of (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm triyng to get the system layout inflater in kotlin: if i convert `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` to kotlin I get `val inflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater?` but it seems to be wrong. So what's the equivalent in kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the equivalent. You just have a null-protected cast, in case that service is null (it shouldn't ever be, but it does happen occasionally).

To make calls on your `inflater` variable, you can just use `inflater?.method()`.

Alternatively, just change `as LayoutInflater?` to `as LayoutInflater` to avoid using the null-safe syntax.

As another option, you could just use `LayoutInflater.from(this)`, which is basically just a convenience function, but it avoids you having to cast.